# Can't write to imported SQLite database Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have imported an already existing database into my app's `assets/databases` folder. The problem is I cannot write to it or truncate a table (`DETELE FROM`) - only read. Also, I am not getting any kind of exceptions.

I am calling `DatabaseAccess` from an adapter using the context I am passing to the constructor from its parent activity.

(I can see the database is opened in the AndroidStudio's Database Inspector)

DatabaseOpenHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Products.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

DatabaseAccess.java:

```
public class DatabaseAccess {

    private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private static DatabaseAccess instance;

    private DatabaseAccess(Context context) {
        this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
    }

    public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void openDatabase() {
        this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase(){
        return openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
        return openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    }

    public void closeDatabase() {
        if (database != null) {
            this.database.close();
        }
    }

    public void insert(CartItem item) {
        try {
            String query = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,"INSERT INTO main.CART_CONTENT (ITEM_DESCRIPTION, PRODUCER, UNIT_PRICE, QUANTITY) VALUES (\"%s\", \"%s\", %.2f, %.2f);",
                    item.getName(),
                    item.getProducer(),
                    item.getUnit_price(),
                    item.getQuantity());
            if(database != null) {
                database.rawQuery(query, null);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public CartItem checkForProduct(CartItem item) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM main.CART_CONTENT " +
                "WHERE ITEM_DESCRIPTION = \"%s\" AND PRODUCER = \"%s\"";
        query = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, query, item.getName(), item.getProducer());

        Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(query, null);

        CartItem updatedItem = new CartItem();
        if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            updatedItem = new CartItem(
                    cursor.getString(1),
                    cursor.getString(2),
                    Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3) + item.getUnit_price()),
                    Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(4)) + item.getQuantity());
            cursor.close();
            insert(updatedItem);
            return  updatedItem;
        }
        else {
            insert(item);
            return item;
        }
    }

    public void emptyDatabase() {
        try {
            database.rawQuery("DELETE FROM CART_CONTENT", null).close();
            database.rawQuery("DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='CART_CONTENT';", null).close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Also, I am not getting any kind of exceptions.

That is because you are trapping exceptions in a try .... catch, something that is not recommended for SQLite access (as it hides errors such as syntax errors). I'd suggest that if you looked in the log, that you would find trapped exceptions.

The insert will certainly have issues as it appears to ignore:-

> A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in **single quotes (')**. A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two single quotes in a row - as in Pascal. **C-style escapes using the backslash character are not supported because they are not standard SQL**. [SQLite SQL Language Expressions - 3. Literal Values (Constants)](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#literal_values_constants_)

I'd suggest using the SQLiteDatabase convenience methods rather than the rawQuery method. These build the underlying SQL, binding the values.

- see [insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) (paying some attention to insertOrThrow and insertOnConflict) and [delete](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D))

So perhaps consider replacing the `insert` and `emptyDatabase` methods in DatabaseAccess with :-

```
public long insert(CartItem item) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("ITEM_DESCRIPTION",item.getName());
    cv.put("PRODUCER",item.getProducer());
    cv.put("UNIT_PRICE",item.getUnit_price());
    cv.put("QUANTITY",item.getQuantity());
    return database.insert("CART_CONTENT",null,cv);
}

public int emptyDatabase() {
    int rv;
    database.beginTransaction();
    rv = database.delete("CART_CONTENT",null,null);
    database.delete("sqlite_sequence","name=?",new String[]{"CART_CONTENT"});
    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
    database.endTransaction();
    return rv;
}
```

- Note that the insert is INSERT OR IGNORE
- `insert` returns the rowid of the inserted row (aka the column that has AUTOINCREMENT encoded and is thus an alias of the rowid column)

  - P.S. there is a very high likelihood that AUTOINCREMENT is just wasting resources - see [SQLiteAutoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html). However, **note** that if excluding AUTOINCREMENT, that deleting the row from the sqlite_sequenece is not needed and would result in a table not found failure if the CART_CONTENT is the only table that has AUTOINCREMENT.
- `emptyDatabase` returns the number of rows that were deleted from the CART_CONTENT table.
- the try .... catch block/clause has been intentionally omitted. Many SQLite problems on SO are not realised because of the use of try .... catch.
- the beginTransaction, setTransctionSuccessful, endTransaction isn't essential and wouldn't be of any use if you omit AUTOINCREMENT.

***Note the above code is in-principle code, it has not been compiled or run and may include small errors***